# Symfony2 and Doctrine ManyToMany realtionship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am heaving some headache about this and I don't find the solution.

I have 2 entities: Movie.php and Category.php

I want one Movie to have multiple Categories and vice versa. That's why I chose a ManyToMany relationship.

Now I am wondering... What happens on the database site? Is there a "in-between" table that maps movie_ids to category_ids? But that's not what happened. Actually my first try was to make a MovieCategory entity - I mapped one movie to multiple categories with OneToMany and in the MovieCategory entity I made a OneToOne connection to get the category name from my Category entity. But I guess that's not how it should work, am I right?

Now here's my code of how i think it should work, I really appreciate any help I can get on this:

Movie.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="movies")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */

class Movie
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $moviename;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="movie")
 */
protected $categories;

}
```

Category.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */

class Category
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->movies = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
*/
protected $name;

// ...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Movie", mappedBy="movie", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $movies;


}
```

Comment: why make a movie have many categories? a movie can't be "horror" and "drama" at the same time, it's either one. i don't think you need a many-to-many relationship between movie and category. it should be many-to-one from movie to category, and one-to-many from category to movie

Comment: ManyToMany relations can be a real pain because Doctrine does indeed create a join table.  Lots of majic going on.  It's easier to just create your own join entity (MovieCategory) and then establish OneToMany relations with it.  Especially iof you want to hang additional attributes on the join entity.

Comment: @Cerad: However if you don't need or want any data hanging on the MovieCategory(Or in my case UserRole), it's a /lot/ easier to just use the "majic". I know what it's doing, and how it does it. I just couldn't remember the Annotation commands :/

PS: Making this comment mostly for informative notes. (I'm one who ends up on SO often looking for information, so I like when people have made comments like these)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) it should look this way:

```
// Movie.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="movies")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="movies_categories")
 */
protected $categories;

// ...

// Category.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Movie", mappedBy="categories")
 */
protected $movies;
```

Comment: +1 you're a genious man. Tried to figure that out for hours... Thanks! :)

Comment: I guess the link is updated to this: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same value for mappedBy in both declarations. Plus, the value you use is singular, it should be plural. This cannot work.